# animate scrolltop not working in chrome, it works in firefox

Tags: jquery

Here is the code

```
$(window).load(function(){
        $('#loader').fadeOut(800, function(){
            $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: $("#jobscroll").offset().top},800 );
        });

    });
```

Ok so the first statement is fading out a loading image that I have covering the entire page until everything is loaded..
After the page loads I want it to scroll down to a specific spot on the page #jobscroll.
This code works perfectly on firefox.. Doesn't work on chrome, I haven't checked other browsers  yet, just focusing on chrome...

I have searched for the answer to this and found numerous stackoverflow pages that seemed to work for others - Yet it hasnt fixed my problem.. Any help on this would be appreciated.. Thanks

Comment: your jquery code is fine, can you give the html code? does somesign changing during the loading? like the position of the #jobscroll?

Comment: Can you do a jsFiddle cause your code look ok at first sight?

Comment: try to add an alert or a console log in the callback to know if the `$("#jobscroll").offset().top` has a value in Chrome or is undefined

Comment: I'm not a jquery pro... what should I alert to the console? I did a console.log("hey"); in the callback, not sure if thats what you meant, but it did tell me hey in the console.

Duan, Romandir. It's mostly PHP, & I don't really want to post the URL on here..

Comment: @variablenate Errors will appear in the console without a `console.log`. I assume that the missing `;` at the end is a typo only in the post. Try selecting only `body`, and not `body,html`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't select `html`, just `body`:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#loader').fadeOut(800, function(){
        $('body').animate({scrollTop: $("#jobscroll").offset().top} ,800);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did try with just body, and just html just now. Neither worked.. drivin me nuts lol.. I have this same script on another website and it works all browsers.. I'm wondering if it has to do with the #loader

`code`<?php if(isset($_GET['q'])&& isset($_GET['loc'])) { // show the loading image if search button is pressed?>
<div id="loader">
    <p class="text-center"><img src="/img/384.gif" alt="Loading.. "></p>
    <h3 class="text-info text-center">Loading Results..</h3>
</div>
<?php } ?>
`code`
That is the code for the loader

Comment: I messed that up.. meant
    <?php if(isset($_GET['q'])&& isset($_GET['loc'])) { // show the         loading image if search button is pressed?>
    <div id="loader">
    <p class="text-center"><img src="/img/384.gif" alt="Loading.. ">          </p>
    <h3 class="text-info text-center">Loading Results..</h3>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>

Comment: @variablenate use a ` to format code in comments. Can you post the output of the PHP instead?